# How do I suppress the title bar and window decorations on a maximized window in Gnome 3.12?

Tags: gnome3, window-manager, window-decorations

I'm trying to get rid of the top title bar on a fullscreen-sized window under Gnome 3.12.2, using the gnome-shell WM. In earlier versions of Gnome this was not difficult to do, but it apparently has become impossible in recent versions. The "Maximus" extension doesn't work correctly for me (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/354/maximus/); it makes the title bar narrower but doesn't remove it.

What are my options, if any, for making this work?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try out "Maximus Two": https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/844/maximus-two/? I was looking for the same thing and come across this. I'm using it now on Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 with Gnome 3.14.4 and it seems working fine.